# Can not log in Elementary after install ubuntu 18.04 (dual boot)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, elementary-os

I am new to Ubuntu 18.04. It has been a long time that I have not updated anything new on my current OS which is Loki (interestingly, besides Loki does not allow ppl to upgrade Juno).

For some reasons, I have to install another Linux OS on my machine, which is ubuntu 18.04 - the minimal installation. Although everything works perfectly to Ubuntu, it makes me cannot log in to my main OS.

Description of an issue: After selecting a boot of elementary, I log in my account on a log-in page of Elementary. It does not show anything else and move back to the log-in. Another try with a guest account (with no password), still the same problem.

Because most of my data and work in Elementary, I have to find a way to solve this problem. Is there anyone here giving me a hand? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Trying `tty` mode by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I was able to log-in in a terminal. Turn out that the Ubuntu has used almost the left memory to load an OS. By removing some files by the command `rm -rf [filename]` to release around 2GB, I was able to have everything back. It was freaking for a while. Phewww...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem once.

Login into `tty` mode by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>,and enter:

1. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
2. `sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils`
3. `sudo reboot`

And I was able to login